# how to get rid of leading zeroes in js calculator

Tags: javascript

So I am making a simple calculator in javascript. I am trying to figure out how to get rid of the leading zeros. I have researched various ways of how to do this but the zeros are still appearing. Any help would be nice.

```
const numberButton = document.querySelectorAll('.number'); //console.log(numbers)
const operatorButton = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');
const toolButton = document.querySelectorAll('.others');
const screenDisplay = document.querySelector('.screen_display')

let display;

numberButton.forEach(num => {
    num.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        let strNum = e.target.value;
        if (number === "0") {
            display = screenDisplay.innerHTML = parseInt(strNum)
        } else {
            display = screenDisplay.innerHTML += parseInt(strNum)
        }

        if (display.length > 16) {
            alert("stop")
        }

    })
})
```

Comment: I'm confused by `let strNum = e.target.value; if (number === "0") {...` - Where does `number` get assigned?

Comment: number is a global variable. I erased it by accident. I didnt want to put e.target.value inside parseInt which is why i assigned it to a variable strNum

Answer (score 2):

Method 1 : Using regular expression

```
number.replace(/^0+/, "")
```

Method 2 : Using parseInt function

```
parseInt(number, 10)
```

Method 3 : Using unary operator

```
+number
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trim leading zeros with replace

```
strNum = strNum.toString().replace(/^0+/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert Integer into String using .toString() . Then you can remove leading zero by using .substring(1,);

Hope this will be helpful !

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the calculator `state` as a number, not a string. This way you can perform basic arithmetic per each button press. There doesn't need to be any special conditions for pressing of `0` -

```js
function onClick(event)
{ event.preventDefault()
  switch (event.target.value)
  { case "1": case "2": case "3":
    case "4": case "5": case "6":
    case "7": case "8": case "9":
    case "0":
      state = (state * 10) + Number(event.target.value) // basic math
      break
  }
  render()
}

function render()
{ calc.display.value = String(state)
}

const calc = 
  document.forms.calc                   // calc DOM node

let state =
  0                                     // initial state
  
calc.addEventListener("click", onClick) // single event listener
```

```css
#calc {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

output {
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  margin: 0 0 0.25rem;
}

button {
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form id="calc">
  <output name="display">0</output>
  <button value="1">1</button>
  <button value="2">2</button>
  <button value="3">3</button>
  <button value="4">4</button>
  <button value="5">5</button>
  <button value="6">6</button>
  <button value="7">7</button>
  <button value="8">8</button>
  <button value="9">9</button>
  <button value="0">0</button>
</form>
```